# strange javascript behavior - JSON.parse: unexpected character

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter

i have the following button :

```
<button onclick='enroll(<?php echo $course['cs_id']; ?>)'>enroll</button>
```

when the user click on it the following javascript function will start :

```
function enroll(id){
    $.post("<?php echo base_url().'courses/enroll/'; ?>"+id , function(data){
     obj = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(obj.state);
    });
    }
```

which perform a post request to php page which echo json array like this :

```
$data = array("state"=>"done");
die(json_encode($data));
```

but unfortunately the following error appears in the console :

**JSON.parse: unexpected character**

i checked the page response and its look like this (which seems fine ) :

```
{"state":"done"}
```

also when i change the enroll() function to be like this :

```
function enroll(id){
$.post("<?php echo base_url().'courses/enroll/'; ?>"+id , function(data){
alert(data);
});
}
```

its show the alert message correctly like this :

```
{"state":"done"}
```

so why it refuse do parse the response where everything seems okay ? any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your code is actually working better than you think! I think that jQuery receives your JSON from the server and realises that it is JSON, even though you haven't specified it as such. (Perhaps your PHP is sending a `Content-Type` header?)

So `data` is actually already a Javascript object, which jQuery has decoded from your JSON. When you call `JSON.parse` on an object, it is converted to a string `[object Object]`, and then parsed. `[object Object]` is evidently invalid JSON, hence the unexpected character error.

---

Since the string was obviously valid JSON, my next guess was that there was some data *before* the string that was causing the parser to be unhappy. The best way to test this is with [`String#charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt), which reveals the precise character at a given point in the string.

So, with the following code, we can test to see what the first character in the string is:

```
console.log(data.charCodeAt(0));
```

You say that this returns `65279`, which, at the beginning of a Unicode document, is a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark). You are apparently outputting this somewhere in your server-side code. You need to find out where that is and remove it.

Comment: so it supposed to work when i do this alert(data.state); without parsing the data , but when i do that it show me "undefined" in alert message.

Comment: @OpEtMaR Could you examine it on the browser console, then, rather than doing `alert`? `console.dir` will give you most information.

Comment: @OpEtMaR I mean `console.dir(data);`

Comment: @OpEtMaR How about `console.log(data.charCodeAt(0));`? Perhaps you're outputting some invisible characters before the data.

Comment: oh , it show 65279 which is a zero-width no-break space ,,,, thanks @lonesomeday , you can put this as answer so i can accept it

Comment: thanks @lonsemeday :) , i just changed the php page encoding to utf-8 without bom and everything works fine now .

Answer (score 1):

Do not parse the data again:

```
function enroll(id){
 $.post("<?php echo base_url().'courses/enroll/'; ?>"+id , function(data){
  alert(data.state);
 });
}
```